# How does Flutter kill the application and still run the logic?

Tags: flutter

I connected the Bluetooth of the watch in the App, and then the Bluetooth connection was disconnected after killing the app. I hope to keep the Bluetooth connection with the watch after killing the app.

I tried using Isolate in Flutter to create an isolate that would run after the App was killed, but it didn't work, and I also used flutter_foreground_task to create a foreground service, but it didn't work either.